# Is Range selection possible in WPF Date Picker?

Tags: wpf, datepicker, relative-date

My requirement is to have some relative date support in my date picker and I want to select start and end date from wpf date picker. But picker showing single calendar and i couldn't achieve two date selection.i have gone through some sites but couldn't get clear answer.

Is it possible to achieve my requirement in WPF date picker or any custom template available for this?

[image]

Thanks,

Indrajeyan.

Comment: It would be more helpful for the people here to answer if you post your code.

Comment: You need to create you custom control for this as default calendar control does not provide any functionality like this. Event you can search for some 3rd party controls. https://www.infragistics.com/samples/wpf/month-calendar/controlling-the-display

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to select two dates, i.e. a start date and an end date, in the same picker? Why don't you use two pickers? Or what is your actual issue?

Comment: Hi @mm8: I dont want to use two picker for this and i knew there is an option to write custom control to acheive this. But i want to know, if anyother option to acheive the same with default date picker control,